# One question about renormalization

Tags: renormalization, perturbation-theory, s-matrix-theory, propagator

The idea of renormalization of "naked" perturbation theory is in principal possibility of addition counterterms which reduce infinity when calculating matrix elements. But I have met such concepts as exact propagator and the exact vertex part. So, the question: are exact propagator and vertex part collected all countreterms of our theory (i.e. all countreterms are convoluted into expressions which are called exact propagators and vertex)? I.e., do they (exact propagators and vertes) contain all information about renormalization of the given theory?

Comment: I suggest coming up with a more informative title.  This will increase interest in this question.